# Criar Array de Objetos em java e acessar os objetos diretamente

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos

Então preciso fazer o seguinte tenho uma classe com alguns atributos e metodos, preciso gerar uma `array` de objetos dessa classe, porem eu queria poder acessa-los diretamente, atualmente o que consegui fazer é joga-los em um `arraylist` e usar o `get(posição)` pra atribui-los em uma variavel temporaria para poder acessar seus metodos e atributos.

Classe a qual quero criar um array de objetos

```
public class BlocoView {
    private MemoriaTextField enderecoMemoria;
    private MemoriaTextField palavras;
    public BlocoView(boolean selected){
        if(selected){
            this.enderecoMemoria = new MemoriaTextField("0", true);
            this.palavras = new MemoriaTextField("???", true);
        }else{
            this.enderecoMemoria = new MemoriaTextField("0", false);
            this.palavras = new MemoriaTextField("???", false);            
        }
    }
    public MemoriaTextField getEndereco(){
        return this.enderecoMemoria;
    }
}
```

Classe que contem o arraylist de objetos da classe acima

```
public class MemoriaView extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList listadeBlocos;
    public MemoriaView(){
        super();
        this.listadeBlocos = new ArrayList();
        this.listadeBlocos.add(new BlocoView(false));
        this.setLayout(new MigLayout());
        //Aqui que tenho que acessar os atributos ou metodos diretamente
        this.add(this.listadeBlocos.get(0));
    }

}
```

Ao tentar fazer algo do tipo

```
this.add(this.listadeBlocos.get(0).getEndereco);
```

o java nao consegue encontrar o metodo get endereco

Comment: o que você quer dizer com `queria poder acessa-los diretamente`?

Comment: Você não precisa colocar em um objeto temporário. Basta saber a posição e fazer assim. arrayList.get(i).getPropriedade().

Comment: @Math acessar do modo que o adelmo00 mostrou

Comment: @adelmo00 ja tentei assim e não funciona, não consigo acessar nem os atributos e nem os metodos

Comment: @alleen94 se você é capaz de atribuir a uma variável do tipo da classe com certeza você pode acessar diretamente tb, conforme o adelmo00 falou. Você deve estar cometendo algum outro erro no caminho, se não conseguir resolver poste o código que está com dificuldade.

Comment: @alleen94 Creio que o problema do OP é que ele não definiu um tipo para a lista, usando Generics, por isso ele só vê um Object ao dar o get.

Comment: @utluiz Exatamente cara defini agora o ArrayList como ArrayList<BlocoView> funcionou certinho obrigado a todos

Comment: @alleen94 Vou acrescentar uma resposta, para não ficar apenas como comentário.

Comment: beleza @utluiz ja seleciono ela como aceita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer isso você deve definir o *tipo genérico* do `ArrayList`, assim:

```java
public class MemoriaView extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList<BlocoView> listadeBlocos;
    public MemoriaView(){
        super();
        this.listadeBlocos = new ArrayList<BlocoView>();
        this.listadeBlocos.add(new BlocoView(false));
        this.setLayout(new MigLayout());
        //Aqui que tenho que acessar os atributos ou metodos diretamente
        this.add(this.listadeBlocos.get(0));
    }

}
```

Sem isso, o tipo da lista fica como Object e, mesmo a instância sendo tipo que você passou, não terá um acesso aos métodos diretamente.

Outra alternativa é fazer um *cast*, assim:

```java
BlocoView bloco = (BlocoView) this.listadeBlocos.get(0);
this.add(bloco.getEndereco());
```